# Put variables in Java pattern

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to know if there is one plugin to put in Eclipse, to change the name of variables or attributes in Java like the pattern camel case.

for example

`myvariable`

will be

`myVariable`

Thanks

Comment: How should it know? Why not `myvariAble`? **Common sense.**

Comment: @ppeterka66 As long as you provide a list of words, this shouldn't be too difficult to do.

Comment: agrred with ppeterka but there is one available for `jetbrains` http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7160

Comment: Not that I know of. If there was, it probably would be neither lightweight nor useful nor friendly.

Comment: @sansix The description in the link you've posted only converts between different conventions, doesn't handle non-conventional names. At least that's what its description says.

Comment: @sansix And I don't see Eclipse under Products.

Comment: How can i install this plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't tell you about any plugins, but I'm not even sure how such a thing would even be able to tell how to change a flat-case name like `myvariable`.

Since you're already using Eclipse, probably the easiest approach is to use the `Rename` refactor option. It is located under `Refactor -> Rename`. On Windows the shortcut is `ALT+SHIFT+R`, and `OPTION+COMMAND+R` on Mac. Simply place the cursor on the entity you wish to rename and either use the menu or hit the shortcut keys.

That will change both the variable (or method, or class...works pretty well on everything)  and all references to that entity, including references from outside the class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This won´t works to my problem, but i helps me to change the name of something, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try [AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/).

In description appears:

```
Convert                     Auto-convert variable names from/to "camel" notation, like
    Camel <-> Underscores   thisIsMyFieldName <-> this_is_my_field_name
```

Comment: But there are no underscores in the original name (although you can get the source code and DIY).

Comment: It didn´t works like I want...Thanks

Comment: I install this plugin and i using the short curt to put in upper case the letter.